# Docker container started before host?

Tags: docker, uptime

Look at the output:

```
ubuntu@iBug-Server:~$ uptime -s
2019-07-07 20:33:07
ubuntu@iBug-Server:~$ docker inspect -f '{{ .State.StartedAt }}' ibot
2019-07-07T12:30:37.871925503Z
ubuntu@iBug-Server:~$ docker restart ibot
ibot
ubuntu@iBug-Server:~$ docker inspect -f '{{ .State.StartedAt }}' ibot
2019-07-08T18:04:50.870117998Z
```

The TZ on my machine is set to `Asia/Shanghai` so its time zone is GMT+8, which translates `20:33:07` into `12:33:07Z`, which is two minutes and a half *after* the container `ibot` started, as given by Docker.

I haven't yet been able to figure out how this happened. The reboot at that time was caused by root user running reboot(8).